# ASP.Net AccountMembershipService moq

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-2, moq

I'm doing a ASP.Net MVC2 project and i want to do some unit tests on it. I tried to test my LogOnController and i have faced some difficulties. In my LogOnController I used AccountMembershipService as,

```
  AccountMembershipService MembershipService = new AccountMembershipService();

    if (MembershipService.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password)){
    ............
    ..........

    }
```

I'm using MOQ framwork and i want to know how to mock AccountMembershipService. Eventhough i have given the correct username and password "`MembershipService.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password)`" always return false. So any one of you have a idea about how to do this..

By the way i have tried the Property injection . But all the time I got the following error..

"Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: x => x.ValidateUser(.validUserName, .validPassword)" .

It comes form the, "`stubService.Setup(x => x.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password)).Returns(true);`"
line.

Here is my code..

```
[TestMethod]
         public void TestLogOn_ValidUserNameAndPassword()
         {
             var controller = new LogOnController();
             var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>(MockBehavior.Loose);
             var model = new LogOnModel();
             var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>(MockBehavior.Loose);
             var stubService = new Mock<AccountMembershipService>();
             model.UserName = "xxxxx";
             model.Password = "123";
             context.SetupGet(x => x.Request).Returns(request.Object);
             controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(context.Object, new RouteData(), controller);
             stubService.Setup(x => x.ValidateUser(validUserName, validPassword)).Returns(true);

             Assert.IsTrue(stubService.Object.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password));

         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Inject the AccountMembershipService to the LogOnController.

  - There are two kinds of injections. The one is constructor injection and the other property injection.
  - The following shows constructor injection.

```cs
public class LogOnController
{
    public LogOnController():this(new AccountMembershipService()){}
    public LogOnController(AccountMembershipService service){ ... } //ctor for injection
}
```

- Make sure ValidateUser method virtual.

  - To mock, method should be virtual, which means the method is interface, abstract or virtual.
- Mock the AccountMembershipService and do testing.

```cs
public void ExampleForMockingAccountMembershipService()
{
    var validUserName = "..";
    var validPassword = "..";
    var stubService = new Mock<AccountMembershipService >();
    stubService.Setup(x=>x.ValidateUser(validUserName,validPassword)).Return(true);

    Assert.IsTrue(stubService.Object.ValidateUser(validUserName, validPassword));
}
```

---

Your problem comes from using unoverridable method, so you should treat it as overridable.
One of solution is adding virtual keyword like the following.

```cs
public class AccountMembershipService 
{
    ...
    public (virtual) bool ValidateUser(string userName, string password)
    {
        ...
    } 
    ...
}
```

Other one is defining interface and mocking the interface instead of actual AccountMembershipService class. To do this, you also need to change the DI(dependency injection) to use interface.

```
public interface IUserValidator
{
    void ValidateUser(string userName, string password)
}
public class AccountMembershipService : IUserValidator
{
}
```

Comment: Hi... Thanks for your help.. I didn't get the idea about constructor injection . By the way i have tried the Property injection before and after you have shown.. But all the time I got the following error..

"Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: x => x.ValidateUser(.validUserName, .validPassword)" .

Comment: You could make ValidateUser overridable with adding virtual keyword, or extrating interface for it and mocking the member of the interface.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you.. Could please post some coding example. I really appriciate your kindness. thankyou. (I have updated my question)